# Python 3.6 updating dict async

Tags: asynchronous, python-3.6

hi I am a new guy working on Python 3.6
I want to update a global dict() asynchronyly.
Here is my dummy code:

```
# prepdt.py
DATA_FROM_PKG = { 'dt1':{}, 'dt2':{} }

def PrepData(data):
    global DATA_FROM_PKG
    if data is not None:
        DATA_FROM_PKG.update(data)
        

# code01.py
from prepdt import PrepData
import time

def func01():
    dt1 = {'dt1':0 }
    a = 0
    while True:
        a += 1
        dt1.update({'dt1':a}) 
        PrepData(dt1)
        time.sleep(1)

func01()

# code02.py
from prepdt import PrepData
import time

def func2():
    dt2 = {'dt2':0 }
    a = 0
    while True:
        a += 1
        dt2.update({'dt2':a})
        PrepData(dt2)
        time.sleep(1)

func2()


#main.py
from prepdt import DATA_FROM_PKG
if __name__ == '__main__':
   while True:
       print(DATA_FROM_PKG)
```

I run `python3 main.py` on a terminal, the result of printing I expect is:

```
{'dt1':, 'dt2':}
{'dt1':, 'dt2':}
{'dt1':, 'dt2':}
...
```

when I run the command `python3 code01.py` on the second terminal,  I expect the print result on main.py terminal should be:

```
...
{'dt1':{'dt1':0}, 'dt2':}
{'dt1':{'dt1':1}, 'dt2':}
{'dt1':{'dt1':2}, 'dt2':}
...
```

Then I run the command `python3 code02.py` on the third terminal, I expect the print result on main.py should be:

```
...
{'dt1':{'dt1':3}, 'dt2':{'dt2':1}}
{'dt1':{'dt1':4}, 'dt2':{'dt2':2}}
{'dt1':{'dt1':5}, 'dt2':{'dt2':3}}
...
```

Hopefully, my description can make sense, this question might be related to multiple threading, but I am very new to programming, not quite understand concurrent.
How can I design my code to achieve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but you're right about needing explicit threading. The problem is that each terminal is running its own instance and thus has its own copy of the data.

You might want to check out the [`threading` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), which makes it pretty easy to run multiple threads. Here is a simplified version of your code that might help:

`prepdt.py`

```py
data = {}


def add_data(key, value):
    if key not in data:
        data[key] = []
    data[key].append(value)


def show_data():
    print(data)
```

`main.py`

```py
import threading
import time
import prepdt


def func01():
    a = 0
    for _ in range(5):
        a += 1
        prepdt.add_data("dt1", a)
        print(f"func01 added {a} to dt1...")
        time.sleep(2)


def func02():
    a = 0
    for _ in range(5):
        a += 1
        prepdt.add_data("dt2", a)
        print(f"func02 added {a} to dt2...")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    prepdt.show_data()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=func01)
    print("thread t1 starting...")
    t1.start()
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=func02)
    time.sleep(2)
    print("thread t2 starting...")
    t2.start()

    while t1.is_alive() or t2.is_alive():
        prepdt.show_data()
        time.sleep(3)

    prepdt.show_data()
    print("Done!")
```

If you really want to start processes in different terminals that interact with the same data, I think the best bet would be to write a little server that stores the data that listens for input, and a client that can interact with the server; then different clients could be opened in different terminals... that's a slightly bigger project, however.

Comment: thank you for the kind reply, I will try the server way, that was what I am expecting, hopefully, I can answer my question. can I keep the question open until then?

Comment: @Kylxyz You bet. This [Real Python tutorial on threading](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) might be a good starting point on setting up a server and clients.

Comment: Thank you @Richard Ambler, I fixed the problem. and like you suggested I used the server way.